# Splitting a string in javascript with different delimitters

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

i am creating a function to split a string to calculate some data. For example, this is an input example "34+23-32+3". I tried to tackle the problem in many forms, without using RegExp. This is the code:

```
function calcOp() {
  str = "34+23-32+3";
  frstIndex = 0;
  dArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    switch (str.charAt(i)) {
      case "+" :
      dArray.push(str.slice(frstIndex, i));
      dArray.push(str.charAt(i));
    }
  }
}
```

This is a short example, this gives me dArray = ["34", "+"]; but then no luck, i algo tried to create an array with all the chars of the string and concatenating just the numbers also with no luck, is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also i tried with eval(), but i have read that this is an insecure way of achiving my goal.

Comment: `"34+23-32+3".split(/\+|\-/g)`

Comment: What is your desired result and which cases are possible?

Comment: This wouldn't seem to have anything to do with just "splitting a string". You need to retain the delimiter so you know what operation to perform. There are a million existing questions about evaluating a math expression in JavaScript, perhaps you should check a few of those out: https://www.google.ca/search?q=javascript+eval+math+expression&oq=javascript+eval+math+expression&aqs=chrome..69i57.3199j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, technically i want to do a calculator, in fact, i did the array of chars to keep the delimiter in order to evaluate later, i did thought that just splitting would not do the trick, eval() just takes the whole string and returns the desired value, but i don't know how dangerous it is, read about it and technically is like forbidden to use.

Comment: why not just use regex? You can just match the string to some capture groups pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more operators in the switch, change `firstIndex` to point to the character after the operator, and add the last item after the loop:

```js
var str = "34+23-32+3";
var firstIndex = 0;
var dArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  switch (str.charAt(i)) {
    case "+":
    case "-":
      dArray.push(str.substr(firstIndex, i - firstIndex));
      firstIndex = i + 1;
      dArray.push(str.charAt(i));
  }
}
dArray.push(str.substr(firstIndex));

// Show result in snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(dArray));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, i didn't know that kind of use of the switch case, you are amazing, thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Or like William proposed, a regexp: `"34+23-32+3".split(/([\-\+])/g)`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i'll try it with regexp, i read that eval is secure if you condition it with a regular expression, and that this is one of the places where eval should go, with math ops, thanks again for your answers!

Comment: @user3741129: To use eval you would need a regular expression that validates everything in the expression, not just splits on the operators. Something like `if(/^(*d+[+\-*\/])*\d+$/.test(str)) { ... }`.